# Excel - bar graph over time

Tags: excel, bar-chart

I have data as below:

```
        t1  t2  t3  t1  t3  t4
case-1  3   3   3   1   2   1
case-2  3   4   3   1   2   1
```

t1,2,3 and 4 are kinda activities over time and the number indicates duration. 
I tried to draw "100% Stacked Bar" graph. But, a problem is columns with same activities such as 't1' and 't3' are recognized as different columns/activities, which are needed to be same legend and color. I just want to draw a time frame-based activity bar without duplicate legend properties.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea, though applies a Stacked Bar chart:

[image: SO21944374 example]

Comment: Can you briefly tell the menu selection for this?